# What is COM error 0x80070012 all about then?

Tags: sharepoint, com

A client of ours is having trouble with a SharePoint site. They are seeing the following error (or something similar) appear when they navigate to any pages:

> There are no more files (0x80070012)

Does anyone know what on earth is this error trying say? I've tried to Google for this, but I could not find anything conclusive. I'm assuming that since this is a COM error that it can appear in areas then SharePoint i.e it's not SharePoint specific.

Cheers.
Jas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not a COM error, it is a Windows error reported by a COM component.  You can tell from the facility code, 7 = Windows API.  Windows error 0x12 is ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES, but you already knew that.

The most common usage is in the FindFirstFile and FindNextFile API functions, used to indicate that there are no more files left to enumerate.  Seeing this reported as an error is a programming bug, it is normal that there are no more files left to enumerate.  You'll need to find out where that bug is located, can't help you with that.

Comment: Sorry, yeah it's not a COM error - had COM topics on my mind when I posted this question :) Cheers for the clarification. Possibly SharePoint is getting mixed up with what files it's expecting to work with, so when it enumerating through a file list, there must be something going wrong.